# Ethernet port missing in Jetson TX2

Tags: 16.04, networking, ethernet, ifconfig

I have a [Connect Tech Rudi TX2](http://connecttech.com/product/rudi-embedded-system-with-nvidia-jetson-tx2-tx1/) device that came with Ubuntu 16.04 installed and it had two physical Ethernet ports `eth0` and `eth1` (they also worked).

After upgrading the Jetson platform to a newer version and flashing Connect Tech's BSP there's now only one Ethernet interface visible when I run `ifconfig`.

Is there a config file somewhere where you can enable or disable network interfaces?

Edit: The other Ethernet port is not enabled in the sense it seems to be completely dead, not just a `/etc/network/interfaces` thing.

```
$ ip link show
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: dummy0: <BROADCAST,NOARP> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 52:f3:af:e6:b7:7b brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:04:4b:a7:fc:a7 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
4: tunl0@NONE: <NOARP> mtu 1480 qdisc noop state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1
    link/ipip 0.0.0.0 brd 0.0.0.0
5: can0: <NOARP,ECHO> mtu 16 qdisc noop state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 10
    link/can 
6: wlan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:04:4b:a7:fc:a5 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
7: docker0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default 
    link/ether 02:42:38:e1:a8:a9 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
8: vcan0: <NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 16 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1
    link/can
```

```
$ sudo inxi -SMN -! 31 -y 80
System:    Kernel: 4.4.38-tegra aarch64 (32 bit) Console: tty 16
           Distro: Ubuntu 16.04 xenial
Machine:   No /sys/class/dmi; using dmidecode: no smbios data available. Old system?
Network:   Card: Failed to Detect Network Card!
```

Comment: `ip link show` list it? Add the output of `inxi -SMN -! 31 -y 80` to your post

Comment: Ok, added the outputs.

Comment: I now have another brand new device and it seems to have exactly (well, naturally not **exactly**) the same software. However, there's `enp1s0` in addition to `eth0`. Maybe I somehow installed "wrong" BSP, although everything else is working.

Comment: On the new system `inxi` says that `e1000e` driver is needed for Intel 82574L.